# Product of cyclotomic polynomials

Tags: cyclotomic-polynomials

> Prove that $$\prod_{_{m \mid p_1 \cdots p_n}}\Phi_{2m}(2) = 2^{p_1p_2 \cdots p_n}+1,$$ where $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ are distinct primes.

I was wondering how to use the definitions of cyclotomic polynomials in order to prove this statement. Should we use this definition $$\Phi_n(x) = \prod_{1 \leq k \leq n, \gcd(k,n) = 1}(x-\omega_k^n)?$$

We know that $\prod_{_{m \mid p_1 \cdots p_n}}\Phi_{m}(2) = 2^{p_1p_2 \cdots p_n}-1$, but how do we use this  to solve the question?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we seek to show that

$$\prod_{m|p_1\cdots p_n} \Phi_{2m}(2) = 2^{p_1 p_2\cdots p_n} + 1$$

where the  $p_q$ are distinct odd  primes. We actually  prove the more
general result

$$\prod_{m|p_1\cdots p_n} \Phi_{2m}(x) = x^{p_1 p_2\cdots p_n} + 1$$

We start from

$$\Phi_n(x) = \prod_{d|n} (x^d-1)^{\mu(n/d)}.$$

The proof is by induction on $n.$ Note that

$$\Phi_{2p} = (x-1)^{\mu(2p)} (x^2-1)^{\mu(p)}
(x^p-1)^{\mu(2)} (x^{2p}-1)^{\mu(1)}
\\ = \frac{(x-1)(x^{2p}-1)}{(x^2-1)(x^p-1)}.$$

We get for $n=1$

$$\prod_{m|p_1} \Phi_{2m}(x)
= \Phi_{2}(x) \times \Phi_{2{p_1}}(x)
= (x+1) \times \frac{(x-1)(x^{2p_1}-1)}{(x^2-1)(x^{p_1}-1)}
\\ = x^{p_1} + 1$$

and the base case holds. For the induction we must show that

$$\prod_{m|p_1\cdots p_n} \Phi_{2m}(x)
\prod_{m|p_1\cdots p_n} \Phi_{2mp_{n+1}}(x)
= x^{p_1 p_2\cdots p_n p_{n+1}} + 1.$$

We have from the definition that with $p$ a prime not dividing $b$
it holds that

$$\Phi_{bp}(x) = \prod_{d|b} (x^d-1)^{\mu(bp/d)}
\prod_{d|b} (x^{pd}-1)^{\mu(bp/d/p)}
= \frac{\Phi_b(x^p)}{\Phi_b(x)}.$$

This yields for the LHS

$$\prod_{m|p_1\cdots p_n} \Phi_{2m}(x)
\prod_{m|p_1\cdots p_n} 
\frac{\Phi_{2m}(x^{p_{n+1}})}{\Phi_{2m}(x)}
\\ = \prod_{m|p_1\cdots p_n} 
\Phi_{2m}(x^{p_{n+1}}).$$

By the induction hypothesis this is

$$(x^{p_{n+1}})^{p_1 p_2\cdots p_n} + 1$$

and we have the claim.

**Remark.** Apparently a much simpler proof uses

$$\prod_{d|n} \Phi_d(x) = x^n - 1.$$

We have

$$\prod_{m|p_1\cdots p_n} \Phi_{2m}(x)
= \prod_{m|p_1\cdots p_n} \frac{\Phi_m(x^2)}{\Phi_m(x)}
= \frac{x^{2p_1p_2\cdots p_n}-1}{x^{p_1p_2\cdots p_n}-1}
= x^{p_1p_2\cdots p_n}+1.$$

Comment: why don't you start [from the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) $\Phi_n(x) = \frac{x^{n}-1}{\prod_{d | n,d < n} \Phi_d(x)}$ ?

Comment: Apply Mobius inversion instantly to get from your definition to my starting point as shown in the first paragraph of the Wikipedia entry.

Comment: I know that, what I meant is that you don't need $\mu(n)$, and you don't need more than 3 lines